# Neo4j Desktop 1.1.12 silent installer

Tags: neo4j, silent-installer, neo4j-desktop

Does anyone have details on installing Neo4j Desktop 1.1.12 silently? I have tried every switch I can think of.

Comment: What OS are you on? Why can't you just use the zip version? And you should update to the latest version for performance/security reasons.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/